Please suggest a good book on Material Sciences and Thin Films
I am a fourth semester student of a Bachelor's Degree in Physics.
The only graduate level book that I have read on Solid State Physics is

An Introduction To Solid State Physics by Charles Kittel

But my professor told me to read up on the following topics if I want to be part of a research project with him. Please suggest to me a good introductory book for the same.

Material Sciences
Thin Films
Multiferroic Metals
Transition Metal Oxides


"...my professor told me to read up on the following topics..." Ask your professor what good introductory books he or she would recommend.

I did. He simply asked me to "figure it out myself" and that this was part of the "learning experience". Please recommend any books or source material that you know of.

https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Transition-Metal-Ions-J-Griffith/dp/052111599X

https://www.amazon.com/Solid-State-Physics-Neil-Ashcroft/dp/0030839939

Thank you for your help
